# Is there a way to loop this?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to loop a declaration of a variable?  just a loop to help me declare the variables so i dont have to do the monotonous work of change the numbers of the variable

```js
 var height1 = document.getElementById('height1').value;
 var height2 = document.getElementById('height2').value;
 var height3 = document.getElementById('height3').value;
 var height4 = document.getElementById('height4').value;
 var height5 = document.getElementById('height5').value;
 var height6 = document.getElementById('height6').value;
 var height7 = document.getElementById('height7').value;
 var height8 = document.getElementById('height8').value;
 var height9 = document.getElementById('height9').value;
 var height10 = document.getElementById('height10').value;
 var height11 = document.getElementById('height11').value;
 var height12 = document.getElementById('height12').value;
 var height13 = document.getElementById('height13').value;
 var height14 = document.getElementById('height14').value;
 var height15 = document.getElementById('height15').value;
 var height16 = document.getElementById('height16').value;
```

Comment: Not a declaration but you could put those variables in an array or something. Why do you need all of those individual values? This sounds a bit like an [XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i'm getting these values from a table where a customer will put in dimensions and then ill use those to generate a price quote

Answer (score 4):

This is not a right way of coding that, Just do like,

```
var heights = [];
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[id^=height]")).forEach(function(itm){
  heights.push(itm.value);
});
```

And now you can iterate the array `heights` to manipulate the values as per your requirement.

The logic behind the code is, `querySelectorAll("input[id^=height]")` will select the input elements that has id starts with the text `height`. Since the return value of `querySelectorAll` is a `nodelist`, we have to convert it as an `array` before using array functions over it. So we are using `Array.from(nodelist)`. That will yield an array for us. After that we are iterating over the returned array by using `forEach` and pushing all element's value into the array `heights`.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always an indication that you want an *array*.  Something like this:

```
var heights = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    heights.push(document.getElementById('height' + i).value);
}
```

Then you can reference a value from the array with something like:

```
heights[1]
```

Though *technically* since in JavaScript your window-level variables are indexable properties of the `window` object, you can essentially do the same thing with variable names themselves:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    window['height' + i] = document.getElementById('height' + i).value;
}
```

Then you can still use your original variables:

```
height1
```

Though in the interest of keeping things outside of window/global scope, maintaining the array seems a bit cleaner (and semantically more sensible).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good use case for an object:

```
var heights = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
  heights[i] = document.getElementById('height' + i).value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would put them in an array.

```
var  heights = []
for (i = 1; i < 17; i++) { 
  heights[i] = document.getElementById('height' + i).value;;
}
```

Beware this will give you a hole at the start of the array ie `heights[0]` has nothing in it. If you use this to iterate it won't matter...

```
for (var i in heights) {
  alert(heights[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) when adding elements to an array. Otherwise, things get strange and you essentially end up with an object with numeric properties.

Comment: @MikeC You're right about using push, but with the current approach `heights[i]=..`  you won't have numeric properties, but regular array indexes. The `length` will be updated automatically on a new index.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Yes and no. The `length` will update but [it will be wrong](https://jsfiddle.net/sfu7v4rL/) when you have gaps, such as between 0 and 1 like you have here. Not critical to this exact problem but I'm just saying it's generally best to avoid it due to this kind of weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its time to introduce [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> Generally speaking, a function is a "subprogram" that can be *called* by code external (or internal in the case of recursion) to the function. Like the program itself, a function is composed of a sequence of statements called the *function body*. Values can be *passed* to a function, and the function will *return* a value.

```
function getHeight(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

Call with the wanted `id` and use it like a variable.

```
getHeight('height1')
```